# Handsontable, colWidths: function: how to set a column width fitting content?

Tags: javascript, css, handsontable

My aim is to set the first column's width equal to a certain number and leave other columns' widths untouched. Now I know that setting

```
colWidths: [myValue]
```

actually breaks other columns' widths but this seems to be workaroundable using

```
colWidths: function(index) {
    if(index == 0)
        return myValue;
    return ???
}
```

but I wonder what should I return in the place of `???`? `undefined` doesn't work (well, it works in the same fashion as `colWidths: [myValue]` – every other column gets the same default width). How do I get the "width by content" value for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the option *manualColumnResize* instead of *colWidths* but the same way as in your question (only defining the first column witdh) :

```
manualColumnResize: [myValue]
```

The first column width will be define as your value, the other columns will still be dynamic. (Because of *autoColumnSizeObject* set to **true** by default, which is also changed to **false** when you use *colWidths* option).

You can find a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x12x1rt6/).

Answer (score 4):

I am currently using

```
modifyColWidth: function(width, col){
  if(width > 300) return 300;
}
```

Referencing by col number would work as well.

```
modifyColWidth: function(width, col){
  if(col === 0) return 300;
}
```

Edit: You would also need this after HandsOnTable have been instantiated, otherwise you cannot set the width beyond 300px.

```
colWidths = [];
[...Array(hot.countCols()).keys()].map(i => {
  colWidths.push(hot.getColWidth(i));
});

hot.updateSettings({
  modifyColWidth: ()=>{},
  colWidths: colWidths
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case, I'll post another method that I've found (posted at GitHub):

using `var autoColumnSize = handsontableInstance.getPlugin('autoColumnSize');` and `autoColumnSize.calculateColumnsWidth(index, 0, true);` – this one calculates the necessary width for the column `index` at row `0` and using `Math.max` is another option. Here's an implementation – without iterating through all the rows and looking for the maximum, but a proof of principle: http://jsfiddle.net/7u1kxjLe/39/